# Why Budd buried Beatrix with a flashlight?

Tags: plot-explanation, kill-bill

I recently watched the Kill Bill movies. In Vol. 2 in the texas funeral scene Beatrix Kiddo is buried alive with a flashlight. But I don't understand why Budd gives Beatrix the chance to see something when she is buried alive. If he want that she suffers he could use the mace. As for myself I think he wants to give her a little chance of survive and get the possibility for revenge. Because in a scene before Budd says to Elle Driver:

> Budd: That woman deserves her revenge and we deserve to die.

**Is there any evidence why Budd gives the flashlight to Beatrix before she gets buried alive? Or another good question could be: is Budd 100 % sure that Beatrix is going to die?**

You can watch the scene here:

Comment: I would bet that it was just a device Tarantino used to allow us, the audience, the logical reason to be able to visually see Beatrix in the coffin. No proof, just thinking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Paulster2 said, it is given audience to visualize the scene. Otherwise it will be just a dark scene and them boom she is out.

For other reason, I got the below mentioned answer from this [thread](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=1446819)

> 1. Bud is a sadistic SOB.
> 2. Giving her a flashlight lets her see her surroundings, and the psychological horror of SEEING that you're trapped with no way out is
>      even greater than of being in pitch dark.
> 3. The terror induced as the batteries in the flashlight fade is even greater.